# PrimeNG textarea with custom format

Tags: typescript, textarea, primeng, quill

is there an easy solution or a custom component to be able to have a textarea where the user can write text only with this format:

```
1. text text text
    a. text text text (2nd level)
        1) text text text (3rd level)
```

When reading the content of the text area the text should be in html.
I tried with Quill but it does not offer custom format rules.
Any advice?
Thanks